Are laws of physics a subset of laws of nature?
This is somewhat similar to my previous question, here: Is there a distinction between laws of nature and laws of physics?. My current question is, are laws of physics a subset of laws of nature? And if it is a subset, is it a proper subset or the same set? I believe laws of physics are a subset of laws of nature, but I am unsure whether there are laws of nature which are not laws of physics. Also, I would be very interested to read what philosophers, especially philosophers of physics, have written about this topic.

Your linked previous question has already an answer, which you have accetepd, and which explains why laws of physics are a proper subset of laws of nature. Hence your present question is a double.

Broadly no, unless you first rule chemistry out of physics. Failing that, which law of nature might not be another way of stating a law of physics?

It depends. As usual the phrases are overloaded with multiple related but incompatible definitions.
The properties of nature described by physicists, which are often called "the laws of physics" but somewhat less often "laws of physics", are properties of nature, which are often called the laws of nature.
The practical models used by physicists, which are often called "laws of physics" but somewhat less often "the laws of physics", are not properties of nature, but approximate maps of the properties of nature. If we ever get exactly true laws of physics of this kind they will still be maps, not properties. Laws of physics of this kind are not usually called laws of nature.
"Physical law" can be used to denote both concepts.
"Natural law" may rarely be used to denote either of the concepts denoted by "physical law". However, it usually denotes a concept having to do with morality and teleology derived from observation of nature. This concept is mostly unrelated to anything denoted by "laws of physics" or "physical law".
In addition, "laws of nature" can also denote instinctive behavior in animals or humans. This concept is mostly unrelated to anything denoted by "laws of physics".

The ancient Greek word for nature is physis, from which the English word 'physics' derives.  Issac Newton didn't call himself a physicist, he called himself a natural philosopher, but they are the same.  So based on the etymology you could say x is a law of physics if and only if X is a law of nature, so laws of physics are a subset of the laws of nature, but not a proper subset.
Suppose you reject the etymological approach. As a physicist, I can tell you that my field covers the whole of existence.  Anything in the universe can be understood using physics. Therefore it is the chief science.  All of chemistry is a subset of physics.  Now consider neurobiology.  At first it didn't appear to be a subset of physics, it had its own words which weren't understood by physicists.  One of those words was 'neuron'.  But when the time came to understand what a neuron does, and how it works, physicists were needed.  The neuron was modeled as a capacitor, something physics explained well.  So although some laws of nature seem not to be laws of physics at first sight, after close inspection they always are laws of physics too, since physics is all encompassing.
